# R Winsorizing with specific cut-off values does not work

Tags: r, trim, desctools

I want to winsorize my data using the mean plus (/minus) 2 standard deviations of the variable as cut-off points. I thus want to winsorize every variable one by one.

The variable I want to winsorize in the example code I provided below has 5 outliers.

I have created two benchmarks (high and low) and have inserted them in minval and maxval.
Just to prevent misunderstandings: I have several timepoints and groups in my data frame, the grepl-part is to just get one group at one measurement point for the winsorizing.

My code so far:

```
library(DescTools)

benchhigh <- mean(ds$RRS[grepl('^34.*', ds$QUESTNNR)], na.rm=TRUE) + 
              2*sd(ds$RRS[grepl('^34.*', ds$QUESTNNR)], na.rm=TRUE)

benchlow <- mean(ds$RRS[grepl('^34.*', ds$QUESTNNR)], na.rm=TRUE) - 
              2*sd(ds$RRS[grepl('^34.*', ds$QUESTNNR)], na.rm=TRUE)

ds$RRSout <- Winsorize( ds$RRS[ grepl('^34.*', ds$QUESTNNR) ], 
                        minval = benchlow , maxval = benchhigh, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The error I get is:

> "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, RRSout, value = c(1, 1.33333333333333,  : 
>     replacement has 38 rows, data has 510"

My replacement only has 38 rows because the ^34.* group has only 38 participants. I have to winsorize the outliers per group and measurement point though...

How can I replace/winsorize the outliers of the specific participant group in the RRS variable?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why not propose a [MCVE] of similar structure but smaller than your actual dataset?

Comment: Actually I will edit the whole dataset but in four groups. So after group 34, I want to winsorize outliers of group 32 and so on. My goal is thus a complete variable which consists of the results of four winsorized groups.

Answer (score 0):

Your input to `Winsorize()` is restricted to certain observations (`grepl('^34.*', ds$QUESTNNR)`). You can only append the result to the same number of (and ideally the exact same) rows:

```
    ds$RRSout[ grepl('^34.*', ds$QUESTNNR) ] <- 
         Winsorize( ds$RRS[ grepl('^34.*', ds$QUESTNNR) ], 
                    minval = benchlow , maxval = benchhigh, na.rm = TRUE)
```